# Video play only on scrolling to its location on an Elementor Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, video, elementor

I've been using Elementor to design a site and the client wants a video at the end of a page which plays only when the user gets to it.  I'm new to Elementor, and I'm struggling to implement the JS required to do this.

Here's what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<h1>Video Scroll Autoplay</h1>
<div class='scroll-spacer'><h2>Content</h2></div>
<div class='video-wrap'>
  <video autoplay muted playsinline loop poster="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    <source src="https://www.global-wrestling.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Domination-1-Credits.mp4">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>
<div class='scroll-spacer'><h2>Content</h2></div>
```

**JS**

```
window.addEventListener('load', videoScroll);
window.addEventListener('scroll', videoScroll);

function videoScroll() {

  if ( document.querySelectorAll('video[autoplay]').length > 0) {
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight,
        videoEl = document.querySelectorAll('video[autoplay]');

    for (var i = 0; i < videoEl.length; i++) {

      var thisVideoEl = videoEl[i],
          videoHeight = thisVideoEl.clientHeight,
          videoClientRect = thisVideoEl.getBoundingClientRect().top;

      if ( videoClientRect <= ( (windowHeight) - (videoHeight*.5) ) && videoClientRect >= ( 0 - ( videoHeight*.5 ) ) ) {
        thisVideoEl.play();
      } else {
        thisVideoEl.pause();
      }

    }
  }

}
```

All good so far. However... If I add that in to Elementor as a HTML snippet, and try to call the script with

```
<script src="locationofscript.js"></script>
```

the video simply auto-plays when the page loads.

I've also tried adding the JS inline with the same result.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks so much!
Scott

Comment: Have you tried removing the autoplay attribute that tells the video to play as soon as the user interacts with the page? :)

Comment: @ScottDavies is the problem solved now?